# How can I format values from std::vector to std::string efficiently?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stringstream

I have a program that takes a `std::vector<uint8_t>` and returns a `std::string` formatted as hex characters followed by the ASCII text like so:

03 00 00 54 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ASCII ...T............

74 21 B8 30 00 2C 2E 31 62 30 74 21 A8 30 00 2C ASCII t!.0.,.1b0t!.0.,

This is the main part of the code:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> value;
std::stringstream printed_line;
std::stringstream tempHexLine;
std::stringstream tempAsciiLine;

for (size_t printed_bytes = 0; printed_bytes < value.size(); printed_bytes += bytes_line) {

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes_line; ++i) {
        tempHexLine << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::uppercase << std::hex << static_cast<uint16_t>(value[printed_bytes + i]) << " ";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes_line; ++i) {

            if(isprint(value[printed_bytes + i])) {

                if (value[printed_bytes + i] == 60) {
                    tempAsciiLine << "&lt;";

                } else if(value[printed_bytes + i] == 62) {
                    tempAsciiLine << "&gt;";

                } else {
                    tempAsciiLine << static_cast<char>(value[printed_bytes + i]);
                }

            } else {
                tempAsciiLine << ".";
            }
        }
    }

    printed_line << tempHexLine.str() << "   " << tempAsciiLine .str();
```

The problem that I'm trying to solve is that when the vector size is large (> 1000 elements), the this takes a long time - approximately 70% of the samples using Very Sleepy where to the `::operator<<` function.

What is the fastest way to apply a format like this to the values in the vector? There are well defined chucks of data that the vector needs to be broken into, so it seems like outputting a byte at a time is an inefficient way.

Comment: Define "it takes a long time" in terms of real time, not percentage.

Comment: Is this with full compiler optimization enabled?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - The time spent in this function is over 4 minutes of the 5-6 minute runtime.

Comment: Stream IO isn't known for being speedy. This is a trivial conversion, if you really need speed I'd opt for custom code to do it.

Comment: @packersfan16: Surely that makes sense. If your program's task is to produce output, it should not come as a surprise that the majority of its time is spent producing output. That being said, standard C++ I/O and I/O manipulators are not fast in a tight loop.

Comment: @packersfan16 - Also, as the other comment suggested, are you running this with optimizations enabled?  If not, and this is some sort of "debug build" version, then your results are basically worthless until you build an optimized version and test it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is not surprising that this much time is being spend producing the output, I am just looking for a way to maximize its efficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be trivial to write efficiently. Try this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::string to_hex(std::vector<uint8_t> const & v)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(4 * v.size() + 6);

    for (uint8_t c : v)
    {
        static constexpr char alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

        result.push_back(alphabet[c / 16]);
        result.push_back(alphabet[c % 16]);
        result.push_back(' ');
    }

    result.append("ASCII ", 6);
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(result));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If the OP wants dots displayed for non-printable ASCII, then maybe `std::transform` at the end instead of `std::copy` to set non-printables to dots.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: OK, good point. Left as an exercise to the reader :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might use some conversion tables for individual characters:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class HexadecimalTable
{
    public:
    static const unsigned ElementSize = 4;

    HexadecimalTable();

    const char* operator [] (std::uint8_t value) const {
        return m_table[value];
    }

    private:
    typedef char hex_type[ElementSize];
    hex_type m_table[256];
};

HexadecimalTable::HexadecimalTable() {
    static const char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        m_table[i][0] = hex[i / 16];
        m_table[i][1] = hex[i % 16];
        m_table[i][2] = 0;
    }
}

class EntityTable
{
    public:
    static const unsigned ElementSize = 8;

    EntityTable();

    const char* operator [] (std::uint8_t value) const {
        return m_table[value];
    }

    private:
    typedef char entity_type[ElementSize];

    entity_type m_table[256];
};

EntityTable::EntityTable() {
    // Printable and non printable characters
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        if(std::isprint(i)) m_table[i][0] = char(i);
        else m_table[i][0] = '.';
        m_table[i][1] = 0;
    }
    // Special characters
    std::strcpy(m_table['<'], "&lt;");
    std::strcpy(m_table['>'], "&gt;");
    // ...
}

std::string hex_display(std::vector<uint8_t> const & v) {
    HexadecimalTable hexadecimal;
    EntityTable entities;

    std::string result;
    result.reserve((HexadecimalTable::ElementSize + EntityTable::ElementSize) * v.size());

    for (uint8_t c : v) {
        result.append(hexadecimal[c]);
        result.push_back(' ');
    }

    for (uint8_t c : v)
        result.append(entities[c]);

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> v = {
        0x74, 0x21, 0xB8, 0x30,
        0x00, 0x2C, 0x2E, 0x31,
        0x62, 0x30, 0x74, 0x21,
        0xA8, 0x30,   60,   62
    };
    std::cout << hex_display(v) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```